# UITableView dislocates automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

**Issue**

I am encountering a weird issue with `UITableView`. Following is the link to video that explains the issue I'm facing. (turned on slow animation)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/UITableView_Issue.swf

The table is dislocating only when the controller is visited for the first time. Later on, the issue isn't popping.

**Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
    [self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _extrasTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 44, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 75, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - 44) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_extrasTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _extrasTable.rowHeight = CGRectGetHeight(_extrasTable.bounds) / 5;
    _extrasTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _extrasTable.dataSource = self;
    _extrasTable.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_extrasTable];];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [EXTRAS count];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:NobileMedium size:15];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = EXTRAS[indexPath.row];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        return cell;
    }

#pragma mark - Visible cells
- (NSArray*)visibleCells
{
    return [_extrasTable visibleCells];
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm adding this TableView' controller as a subview to another View controller. The code for the same as follows:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
[currentController removeFromParentViewController];//currentController - instance of UIViewController
MMExtrasVC *controller = [[MMExtrasVC alloc] init];//the controller that contains table view
controller.view.frame = [[self view] bounds];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
currentController = controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ViewDidLayoutSubView` and set Frame there for your table.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _extrasTable setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
}
```

Comment: Did. Still having same issue!

Comment: Are you using interface builder and/or storyboard with constraints? Also can you post the code where the ViewController is instanciatied

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé I'm not using xib/storyboard. Will update the post to show the initialisation code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the navigation bar.

Firstly, I would try removing below from viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
```

Secondly, I would remove the tick (if there's one) from:

```
Extend Edges, Under Top Bars
```

from the Attributes Inspector of the view controller.

Comment: Removed `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;`, same issue.

Not using, storyboard/xib. Changed in Main storyboard - no effect!